# How to set up an iOS app to have perpetual memory?

Tags: swift, memory-management, ios8, swift2, ios9

I am asking what code to use to save user data in the app so that it is perpetual, even after the app is closed and reopened. I watched a few videos but my code isn't working.

I'm not interested in fixing code, I want to understand the process so I can reapply. Can anyone help me to understand how to do this and explain it in a way that makes sense for long term app development.

Comment: Show the code and describe your specific problem. This site is not a replacement for manufacturer's tutorials and SDK documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will differ by application, depending on how much data and how it's organized.

If it's simple stuff, look at `NSUserDefaults`.  If it's complicated and represented as objects, look at `Core Data`.  If there's a lot of it and you see it as table rows rather than objects, you can use the `sqlite3` database directly.  If it has to be shared with other users or by other apps, start thinking about an external server or "the cloud".

There's no single right answer but those options should get you thinking about requirements.